# gdb not hitting breakpoint in kern/entry.S

Tags: operating-system, xv6

I am trying to get gdb to break at the part where paging gets enabled in the kernel (kern/entry.S), I set a breakpoint at the address the disassembler showed (as in kernel.asm) but its not getting hit. Can someone help me understand why this is the case. Earlier also I was unable to hit any breakpoint in the bootloader, boot/boot.S  boot/main.c , for instance i was unable to hit bootmain (setting a breakpoint using function name tells me symbol is not yet loaded), I can check the nm/objdump output and I can clearly see bootmain defined.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: My guess is that you don't have privilege to set a break point in the kernel address space.

Comment: Do you set the breakpoint(s) at the virtual or physical address?

Comment: @Daniel , I set it at the physical address (and was able to hit the address from gdb subsequently), the thing I am still not able to understand is that in the assembly code there is a function call (the function is defined in a c file later), why would gdb not see that function (there are no external libraries being linked), when I set the breakpoint (b functionName<bootmain>, it says not defined and does not  break